# An Experiment with Sine Waves and Water-

Tags: experimental, physical-reaction, illusion

Hey guys,

I cam across this clip on YouTube and what I saw puzzled me.
an this be true at all. (I'm keeping my skeptic face on, for the moment)

[Amazing Water Experiment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=uENITui5_jU)

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed on SSD recently.  A search should find the previous discussion.

EDIT:  Here is the previous post:  [Sending low tone frequencies through water](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/18548/sending-low-tone-frequencies-through-water)